# SQL finding all rows where column is greater than one month and a certain date

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 3 columns ID|dateA|dateB

How could I say I want to find all ID's where dateB is greater than dateA and is the follow month past the 15th day

so for example

```
ID|dateA|dateB
1|1/1/2013|2/20/2013
2|1/3?2013|2/26/2013
3|1/3/2013|4/12/2013
4|1/3/2013|2/5/2013
```

In this example it would find results 1/2/3

Comment: @Hiten004 huh? just simple query...

Comment: How does you tsql look like? did you start?

Comment: What is the following month past the 15th day? dateA or dateB? Nevermind...

Comment: @Asken Meaning dateB has to be the next month and all timeframe greater than that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
select *
from yourtable
where dateA < dateB
  and
  (
    dateadd(day, 14, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, datea)+1, 0)) < dateb
  )
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01417/13)

Comment: Love the SQL Fiddle... didn't know about that.

Comment: @Asken: I agree it was bit confused (I meant `'follow month past ..'`), and I took it off. bluefeet to the rescue. +1